# Syslog Output File Splitting HOURLY at Syslog Server

Tags: cron, rsyslog, syslog, logrotate

I have implemented syslog server on CentOS and using below Template to generate output file on daily basis -

```
$template TmplNationalIP_PL, "/var/log/NIPFW/MX480/CGNAT_PL_%$year%.%$month%.%$day%"
if ($msg contains 'OR_NAT' and $msg contains '55.91.165.') then ?TmplNationalIP_PL
& ~
```

Similar to above (daily), I am looking to split syslog files on HOURLY basis (instead of daily).

How I can split syslog messages files on HOURLY basis  as I couldn't find any HOURLY variables to use?

Also, I am using logrotate + cron jobs but there is no option to rotate hourly basis in logrotate (minimum is daily).

Below is the snip from *cat /etc/logrotate.d/syslog*

```
/var/log/NIPFW/MX480
{
        rotate 50
        daily
        copytruncate
        missingok
        notifempty
        compress
        delaycompress
        dateext
        maxage 30
        sharedscripts
        postrotate
                reload rsyslog >/dev/null 2>&1 || true
        endscript
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**cron and logrotate**

The script `/etc/cron.daily/logrotate` is located in the daily folder.

You have to move it to `/etc/cron.hourly` and change `daily` to `hourly` in your config file.

Comment: thanks @Freddy but moving *logrotate* from */etc/cron.daily/* to */etc/cron.hourly* will also impact every log in the system.

But I wanted to rotate specific syslog as hourly and rest to remain as usual way (daily), like -

 1. Specific logs (*var/log/NIPFW/MX480/*.log*) on *hourly* basis 
 2. Remaining logs (*/var/log/* etc.*) as usual way (*daily*)

Comment: Below is the config file for the same from /etc/logrotate.d/syslog

    /var/log/NIPFW/MX480/*.log
    {
            rotate 50
            hourly
            copytruncate
            missingok
            notifempty
            compress
            delaycompress
            maxage 30
            sharedscripts
            postrotate
                    reload rsyslog >/dev/null 2>&1 || true
            endscript
    }

Answer (score 0):

The hour-based system property for `rsyslog` is appropriately called '$hour'. This is documented under the [rsyslog Properties page](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/properties.html?highlight=hour).

Therefore, you can modify your template as shown below to generate hourly log files:

```
$template TmplNationalIP_PL,"/var/log/NIPFW/MX480/CGNAT_PL_%$year%.%$month%.%$day%.%$hour%"
```